# Tests run under JUnit 4 but not JUnit 5 — Compiles clean, but 0 tests execute

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, junit5, junit-jupiter

Anyone can easily reproduce this problem in a couple minutes.

## Basic Maven `quickstart` project

With IntelliJ 2018.3 and Maven 3.6.0, I create a brand new project using the Maven archetype [`maven-archetype-quickstart`](https://maven.apache.org/archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart/) version 1.4.

[image]

## Java 11

In the POM file of the new project, I change properties for `maven.compiler.source` and `maven.compiler.target` from 1.7 to 11, for the Java 11.0.2 I am currently using, [Zulu](https://www.azul.com/products/zulu-enterprise/) from [Azul Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azul_Systems).

```xml
<properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

On the Maven panel of IntelliJ, I run the `clean` and `install` Lifecycle events.

[image]

## Test runs in JUnit 4

As part of `install`, the tests are run. This `quickstart` archetype comes with one single test that asserts `true`.

[image]

The results appear in the `Run` panel of IntelliJ.

> [INFO] Running work.basil.example.AppTest
>
> [INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.026 s - in work.basil.example.AppTest

So I know the test executed.

## JUnit 5, not 4

This is all good. Now let's upgrade to JUnit 5, to see the problem.

In the POM, I change the JUnit dependency from this:

```xml
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.11</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

…to this:

```xml
<dependencies>
  <!--JUnit 5-->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

### Jupiter imports (no vintage tests)

The compiler complains about my `AppTest.java` file. So I change the `import` statements there to use the `jupiter` packages. I only want to run JUnit 5 tests in my new greedfield project, with no need for vintage JUnit 4 tests. So the imports change from this:

```java
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import org.junit.Test;
```

…to this:

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;
```

Then I execute the `Maven` > `Lifecycle` > `clean` & `install`.

…and voilà, the problem: Our test is not executed. The report seen in the `Run` panel of IntelliJ:

> [INFO] Running work.basil.example.AppTest
>
> [INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 s - in work.basil.example.AppTest

➥ Why does JUnit 5 fail to run the very same test that JUnit 4 happily ran?

## Update `surefire` plugin

I suspect the [Maven Surefire Plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin) needs to be updated. So in the POM I change this:

```xml
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.22.1</version>
</plugin>
```

…to this:

```xml
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
</plugin>
```

Another `clean` & `install`. But no better, still runs 0 tests.

> [INFO] Running work.basil.example.AppTest
>
> [INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.004 s - in work.basil.example.AppTest

## Entire POM

Here is my entire POM file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>work.basil.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>tester</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>tester</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!--JUnit 5-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>5.3.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

## JUnit libraries

After doing a Maven `clean` & `install`, two JUnit libraries appear: `junit-jupiter-api` and `junit-platform-commons`.

[image]

## Other versions of JUnit 5

I tried the following versions in my `junit-jupiter-api` dependency:

- 5.0.0-M1
- 5.1.1
- 5.3.0
- 5.3.2
- 5.4.0-M1

On each attempt, I ran a Maven `clean` & `install`. No better. Each of those versions reported `Tests run: 0`.

## Do not blame `maven-archetype-quickstart`

I actually discovered this problem in a much different project using an entirely different Maven archetype.

To nail down this buggy JUnit 5 behavior, I tried a new fresh project using the very simple `maven-archetype-quickstart`. I found the very same behavior: Everything compiles, the test harness in running, but no tests are executed under JUnit 5.

Comment: Are you aware of the junit-vintage-engine maven artefact? From my experience either add that to run old tests unmodified or invest some work to follow their migration doc (https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#migrating-from-junit4).

Comment: @JensDibbern I am ***not* running vintage tests**. In my Question I explain that I changed the `import` statements to `jupiter`. I want only JUnit 5 on my new greenfield project.

Comment: Did you try with other versions eg. 5.3.0, or maybe 5.0.0-M1 and see if works? Since not coming from the same place maybe the are still issues on compatibility with 4 versions tests, but on trivial test it's should work.

Comment: @TraianGEICU Versions 5.0.0-M1, 5.1.1, 5.3.0, 5.3.2, and 5.4.0-M1 of the `junit-jupiter-api` dependency all fail to run the test.  Added section to the Question.

Comment: Then if all fails, maybe you have right and some additional settings on maven are needed. But which don't have a clue.

Comment: Not sure if any help but if you take a look at following pom : https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/blob/master/junit5-jupiter-starter-maven/pom.xml . There are 2 more dependencies there : junit-jupiter-engine (and params)

Comment: @TraianGEICU Thanks! That seems to have solved my problems, adding 1 of those two dependencies: `junit-jupiter-engine`. I posted [an Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54321267/642706) with the details. I had followed directions elsewhere that said only the one `junit-jupiter-api` dependency was needed, but clearly those directions were wrong.

Comment: It's documented in the User Guide: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## tl;dr

For JUnit 5 version 5.4.0-M1 or later, specify the new single Maven artifact [`junit-jupiter`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter) “Aggregator” in your POM.

```xml
<!--JUnit 5-->
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.0-M1</version>
</dependency>
```

For earlier versions, specify at least these two artifacts: [`junit-jupiter-api`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api) & [`junit-jupiter-engine`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine).

## JUnit 5 yokes multiple testing frameworks

From what I can gather, JUnit 5 has been re-architected to be a yoke for multiple testing frameworks. These testing systems include JUnit 4 “vintage” tests, the new JUnit 5 tests (new syntax for tests, with new annotations & methods), and others such as [Specsy](https://specsy.org/), [Spek](https://spekframework.org/), [Cucumber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cucumber_(software)), Drools Scenario, [jqwik](https://jqwik.net/), and [more that implement](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/wiki/Third-party-Extensions) the [`TestEngine`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/platform/engine/TestEngine.html) interface.

Apparently the `junit-jupiter-api` artifact is only the outer yoke. You must also specify one or more [`TestEngine`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/platform/engine/TestEngine.html) implementations to actually run tests. For example, to run the vintage JUnit 4 tests, you need the [`VintageTestEngine`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/vintage/engine/VintageTestEngine.html) implementations, or to run JUNit 5 tests you need the [`JupiterTestEngine`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org/junit/jupiter/engine/JupiterTestEngine.html) implementation.

So to run your JUnit 5 tests, you must specify a `JupiterTestEngine` implementation in your Maven POM with the `junit-jupiter-engine` artifact.

See the JUnit 5 manual, specifically the section [*Configuring Test Engines*](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build-maven).

See [this presentation](https://youtu.be/0qI6_NKFQsY?t=1560) by Marc Philipp, with a diagram showing JUnit 5 as a platform having (A) a core for IDE/build tools with (B) pluggable test-writing frameworks for programmers authoring tests.

## `junit-jupiter-engine`

As seen on [this sample](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/blob/master/junit5-jupiter-starter-maven/pom.xml), add a second JUnit-related dependency for the [*JUNit Jupiter Engine*](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine). The [documentation for this artifact](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#dependency-metadata) says simply: “JUnit Jupiter test engine implementation, only required at runtime.”.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.0-M1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Simply adding that one dependency to the project shown in your Question will see your tests run.

> [INFO] Running work.basil.example.AppTest
>
> [INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.004 s - in work.basil.example.AppTest

---

## `junit-jupiter-params`

That same sample shows also a third JUnit dependency, for [*JUnit Jupiter Params*](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-params). While not needed to make your example test run, it may serve other purposes. Apparently related to [*Parameterized Tests*](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests).

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.0-M1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

That makes a total of 3 JUnit dependencies.

```xml
<!--JUnit 5-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.0-M1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.0-M1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.0-M1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Your same POM file, now updated to all 3 of these JUnit dependencies.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns = "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation = "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>work.basil.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>tester</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>tester</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!--JUnit 5-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0-M1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0-M1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0-M1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

## `junit-jupiter` artifact

Version 5.4.0 of JUnit 5 brings a new Maven artifact, [`junit-jupiter`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter) titled *JUnit Jupiter (Aggregator)*. The word “aggregator* apparently refers to it bundling a few of the commonly-used JUnit 5 artifacts in Maven, for our programming convenience.

Adding this one single `dependency` in your POM gets you 8 libraries in your project.

```xml
<!--JUnit 5-->
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.0-M1</version>
</dependency>
```

[image: Screenshot of IntelliJ panes for project structure and POM file contents, where a single dependency for <code>junit-jupiter</code> adds eight libraries to your project, all you need to run JUnit 5 tests.]

Comment: Starting with 5.4.0-M1 there's a single aggregator dependency you can use: `org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.4.0-M1`. That will pull in all three `org.junit.jupiter` dependencies.

Comment: @MarcPhilipp Many thanks for the tip about the new single [*JUnit Jupiter (Aggregator)*](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter) artifact replacing the multiple JUnit artifacts in my project’s POM. I tried it and indeed it works. I revised my Answer to incorporate this info. And thanks for all your work – watching one of your YouTube videos now.